# how to gen variable = 1 if at least two dummy variables == 1 in Stata?

Tags: statistics, stata, economics, dummy-variable

I am trying to generate a dummy variable that = 1 if at least two or more (out of seven) dummy variables also == 1. Could anybody tell me an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular? Any code attempts you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that the **indicator variables** concerned (you say "dummy variables", but that's a terminology over-used given its disadvantages) are `x1` ... `x7`. From that definition it is taken that their values are 1 or 0, except that values may also be missing. Then the logic for the summary you want is

```
gen xs = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7) >= 2 if (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7) < .
```

That's not too difficult to type, given copy and paste to replicate the syntax for the sum. The `if` qualifier segregates any observations with missing on any of the indicators, for which missing will be returned for the new variable. Such observations will be reported as having a total `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7` that is missing. Missing is treated as arbitrarily large in Stata, and certainly as greater than 2, which explains why the simpler code

```
gen xs = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7) >= 2
```

would bite you if missings were present.

If you want a more complicated rule, you may find yourself reaching for `egen` functions `rowtotal()`, `rowmiss()`, and so forth. See the help for `egen`.

Comment: The solution I used was  
    gen variable1=0  
    gen variable1=1 if x1 + x2 + x3 == 1  

where == 2 if I am interested in the variable that has 2, >=3 if greater than or = to 3, an so on.    My apologies for the novice question.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment is not clear to me. The code wouldn't run as you post it. If the answer is not what you want, please edit the original question.